# Use A Single Line To Loop Two Dictionaries To Create List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, key

I have looked at several threads similar but unable to get a workable solution. I am looping (2) dictionaries trying to create a single list from the values of one based on the keys of another. I have it done with for loops but looking to use a single line if possible.  My code with for loops

```
  for k, v in dict1.items():
    for value in dict2[k]:
    temp.append(value)
```

On the first loop thru the temp list would be and is from above code:

```
[16,18,20,22,24,26]
```

I then use min to get the min value of the list. Now I want to condense the for loop to a one liner. I have put together

```
temp=[dict2.values() for k in dict1.keys() if k in dict2.keys()]
```

When executed, instead of temp being a single list for the k that exist in the dict1, I get a list of list for all the values from all dict2.

```
[[16,18,20,22,24,26], [12,16,18,20,22,24], [16,18,22,26,30,32]]
```

It seems to be ignoring the if statement. I know my dict1 has only 1 key in this situation and I know the 1 key exist in the dict2. Is my one liner wrong?

Input Values for dictionaries:

```
dict1={'table1':[16,18,20,22,24,26]}

dict2={'table1':[16,18,20,22,24,26],'table2': [12,16,18,20,22,24], 'table3': [16,18,22,26,30,32]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through one dictionary checking for matching keys and create a list of lists. Use `chain.from_iterable` to flatten list and call `min()`:

```
from itertools import chain

dict1 = {'table1': [16,18,20,22,24,26]}    
dict2 = {'table1': [16,18,20,22,24,26], 'table2': [12,16,18,20,22,24], 'table3': [16,18,22,26,30,32]}

temp = [dict2[k] for k in dict1 if k in dict2]

print(min(chain.from_iterable(temp)))
# 16
```

Comment: You can even shorten `list(value for value in dict2[k])` to just `dict2[k]`, I think.

Comment: In case you have only one key in `dict1`, you can use `min(temp[0])` without any imports.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your list comprehension does not work:

It looks like `dict2` has 3 key-value pairs, and the values are `[16,18,20,22,24,26], [12,16,18,20,22,24]`and `[16,18,22,26,30,32]`. What you're doing in your list comprehension translates to

```
for k in dict1.keys():
    if k in dict2.keys():
        temp.append(dict2.values())
```

So if `dict1`has, let's say, 3 keys, this for loop will repeat 3 times. Because, as you said in a comment above, only one key is shared between `dict1`and `dict2`, the `if` statement only is True once, so all items of `dict2.values()` will be appended to `temp`once. What you want to do, if i got that right, is to append all items INSIDE one of the values of `dict2`, namely the one assigned to the one key that the two dicts share. Your idea was pretty close, you just have to add one little thing. As a one liner, it would look like this:

```
temp = [x for x in dict2[k] for k in dict1.keys() if k in dict2.keys()]
```

or, differently:

```
temp = [dict2[k] for k in set(dict1.keys()).intersection(set(dict2.keys()))]
```

Comment: The dict1 will always have less or equal number of keys to dict2. The dict2 is kinda of a master and dict1 was created off of it.  I like both answers that have been provided, they both point out my short comings which is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `itemgetter()`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import chain

dict1 = {'table1': [16,18,20,22,24,26], 'table2': [12,16,18,20,22,24]}    
dict2 = {'table1': [16,18,20,22,24,26], 'table2': [12,16,18,20,22,24], 'table3': [16,18,22,26,30,32]}

common_keys = set(dict1).intersection(dict2)
sublists = itemgetter(*common_keys)(dict2)

if len(common_keys) == 1:
    max_val = max(sublists)
else:
    max_val = max(chain.from_iterable(sublists))

print(max_val)
# 26
```